# AppEngine Remote API NoClassDefFoundError Base64

Tags: google-app-engine

What jar is Base64 in?

com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.class is contained in google-http-client-1.13.1-beta.jar, but adding that to the claspath doesn't resolve it.

I just can't figure out what jar has com/google/appengine/repackaged/...

Grrrr... using Appengine.1.9.25 works but switching in 1.9.37 fails....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/api/client/repackaged/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.util.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(Base64.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature.signUsingRsaSha256(JsonWebSignature.java:634)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:378)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.OAuthClient.get(OAuthClient.java:64)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.getAppIdFromServer(RemoteApiInstaller.java:413)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.loginImpl(RemoteApiInstaller.java:376)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.login(RemoteApiInstaller.java:337)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.install(RemoteApiInstaller.java:173)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use 1.9.26 version. Seems Google missed to package commons-codec into 1.9.37.